# jqGrid subgrid not expanding

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

I'm sure it must be something basic, but I can't figure out why I can't get a subgrid to load:

```
$("#MyTable").jqGrid({
    datatype: function () {
        $("#MyTable").jqGrid("addRowData", 1, { Id: 1, Name: "Someone" });
    },
    height: 90,
    colNames: ["#", "Name"],
    colModel: [
                { name: "Id", index: "Id", width: 45, align: "center", sortable:     false },
                { name: "Name", index: "Name", sortable: false }
            ],
    caption: "My Table",
    subGrid: true,
    subGridType: function () {
        alert(1);
    },
    subGridUrl: "myurl",
    subGridModel:   [ { name: ['No','Item','Qty'], width: [55,200,80] } ]
});
```

Clicking on the + symbol to expand the subgrid does nothing. It doesn't call myurl to fetch the data.

Anybody have any ideas? I also tried using the subGridRowExpanded option instead of subGridModel, but still no luck.

**Answer**:

So the answer is that it simply doesn't allow subgrids with datatype set to either "local" or to a function. It works with datatype "json" and, presumably, "xml" only.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Your main error is in the wrong case of writing of the [subgridtype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid#properties) parameter.

Moreover I strictly recommend you **not use** `datatype` or `subgridtype` as the function if it is not **really** required. The usage of `datatype` in your current example can be replaced with the `datatype:'local'` and `data: mydata` parameter where `mydata` parameter are defined as

```
var mydata = [
        { Id: 1, Name: "Someone" }
    ];
```

Comment: I just tried it with subgridtype (all lowercase), and it still didn't work. I really think that subgrids just don't work with datatype: "local".